# InvalidOperationException being thrown even though Dispatcher is being used

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation, dispatcher

I have to do some user behavior playback in wpf.  I have the user run through the program, and I write to a file the events that I am interested in.  Now I need to read those events back in, and have them be invoked by the computer in a realistic fashion (exact timing is not important).  I know that UIs are fickle and you have to worry about thread ownership, however, I've generally used a `Dispatcher`.  This time, it is not working.

I have a textbox defined globally:

```
TextBox fromBox;
```

Then placed in the constructor: (myGrid is a Canvas)

```
fromBox = textBoxFactory(260, 36, 244);  
fromBox.GotFocus += fromBox_GotFocus;  
fromBox.LostFocus += textBox_LostFocus;  
fromBox.TextChanged += fromBox_TextChanged;  
fromBox.Tag = "From TextBox";  
myGrid.Children.Add(fromBox);
```

My code for simulating mouse clicks:

```
    public static void LeftMouseClick(int xpos, int ypos)
    {
        //Random rand = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
        double scale = 1.25;
        SetCursorPos((int)(xpos * scale), (int)(ypos * scale));
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, (int)(xpos * scale), (int)(ypos * scale), 0, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, (int)(xpos * scale), (int)(ypos * scale), 0, 0);
    }
```

Now, in testing, I know that this line will work to create an event that will successfully activate the textbox.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => LeftMouseClick(200, 200)));
```

However, in my playback, it throws an `InvalidOperationException` because the thread doesn't own it.

On playback, I initialize a timer:

```
System.Timers.Timer viz = new System.Timers.Timer(30);
viz.Elapsed += viz_Elapsed;
viz.AutoReset = true;
viz.Enabled = true;
```

and then the elapsed method:

```
  void viz_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (indexer >= readText.Length) {
            ((System.Timers.Timer)sender).AutoReset = false;
            return;
        }
        String line = readText[indexer];

        string[] tokens = line.Split(':');

        if (tokens[4].Equals("Gaze"))
        {
            int x = Int32.Parse(tokens[5]);
            int y = Int32.Parse(tokens[6]);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => UpdateUI(x, y)));
        }
        else if (tokens[4].Equals("FromBox"))
        {
            if (tokens[5].Equals("Focus")) {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => LeftMouseClick(200, 200)));
            }
            else if (tokens[5].Equals("TextChanged"))
            {
                 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>fromBox.Text = tokens[6]));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tokens);
        }
        indexer++;
    }
```

Eventually the numbers will be read in dynamically. This is purely proof of concept code. The line for changing the text works, the line for focusing the textbox does not.  Why would a `Dispatcher` not work in this situation, and what will?

Comment: Not sure, but you can use `DispatcherTimer` to get rid of all that hassle in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

Update: The intent of the answer is to avoid accessing the textbox regardless of the operation. The use of the MVVM model where a shared ViewModel is used to pass state operations back and forth should be considered on the next run of the non proof of concept application.

> have a textbox defined globally:

One can access it globally but the nature of a textbox resides on the GUI thread exclusively.

---

Even a read operation can cause a failure because the textbox was created on the GUI thread. Unfortunately not everything has been isolated and the focus of the textbox is causing issues even though the process is dispatched.

It would be better if you change the operation to the setting of a flag on your View Model (or any shared resources which has INotifyPropertyChanged) and bind to via style settings(?) which would focus the textbox.

I ran into similar and documented it on my blog article [C# WPF: Linq Fails in BackgroundWorker DoWork Event](http://omegacoder.com/?p=636).

Comment: @MickyDuncan Read was only an example; my ultimate suggestion is to remove any access to the textbox in the thread operation fully as a solution to the problem.

Comment: Agreed, however the OP does appear to be already doing that already by putting such code inside `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`.  Though I like the VM approach, the OP is still going to need to thread marshal changes because changing the VM from a worker thread will fault also

Comment: @MickyDuncan Maybe my post needs to be updated, but the next app (besides this proof of concept) should use an MVVM (shared data via VM) way of sharing data and *avoiding* the use of a textbox in separate thread; even though it *appears* he is doing everything right. By changing the architecture it is hoped to *avoid* the issue he is running into.

Comment: @MickyDuncan Thanks for pointing out where my answer is incomplete.